# Algebra maps defined on the generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider an algebra $A$ over some field $k$ generated by a finite set $S$. Now I have several questions in this phrase:

1. In general, $S$ would not be a $k$-vector space basis for $A$, wouldn't it?
2. If I have a map $\Delta: A\to A\otimes_k A$ defined on all  generators in $S$ and I want it to become an algebra homomorphism, what do I have to check? I think there must be something to check if the answer of 1. is 'Yes'. You can assume that I already know a $k$-vector space basis of $A$.

Comment: Are you studying Hopf algebras?

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is not in general a basis of $A$. The algebra $k[X]$ is finitely generated by $\{X\}$, but this is not a basis as it cannot generate terms such as $X^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the example :) Have you git something in mind for the second part?

Comment: Do you need to find every possible homomorphism $\Delta$?

Comment: No I just want to now: If I hand you an algebra homomorphism of the form $\Delta$ as above and I told you what it does on generators, what would you do in order to show that it is indeed an algebra homomorphism?

Comment: I only ask because as far as I can see you only need to check the normal requirements: $\Delta(s_1+s_2)=\Delta(s_1)+\Delta(s_2)$, $\Delta(s_1s_2)=\Delta(s_1)\Delta(s_2)$ and $\Delta(\lambda s_1)=\lambda\Delta(s_1)$. Unless you need an equivalent formulation in terms of something else.

Comment: So if you choose $a\in A$ and $f\in k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ so that $a=f(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$, $\Delta$ is an algebra homomorphism precisely when you impose the condition that $\Delta(a)=f(\Delta (s_1),\ldots,\Delta (s_n))$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, lets look at maps $f:A \rightarrow B$ defined on our generators where $B$ is some $k$-algebra. Suppose first that $A$ is the free algebra $k[S]$ on the set $S$. Then, by the universal property of the free algebra, every algebra homomorphism $f$ is determined by uniquely by where it sends the generators in $S$, and every choice of where to send generators uniquely determines an algebra homomorphism so there is nothing to check.

In general, $A$ will be a quotient of $k[S]$ by some ideal, say, $I \subset k[S]$. (This ideal is just the kernel of the surjective morphism $k[S] \rightarrow A$ sending each element of $S$ to itself.) Our choice of where $f$ sends the elements of $S$ determines a unique morphism $g:k[S] \rightarrow B$ as above, so we just need to check that this descends to a morphism of $A$, i.e, that $g(I) = 0$.

Comment: So assume my algebra $A$ is the assoc. unital algebra generated by $S=\{a_1,...,a_2\}$ such that some relations holds, i.e. $a_2³=1, a_1a_2+a_2a_1=0$. Then I can write $A=k[S]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal in $k[S]$ generated by $I=<a_2³-1,a_1a_2+a_2a_1>$. (Well, it is more an isomorphic than an equality.) Have I understand you right? What is the universal property of free algebras and where can I find a proof?

Comment: Yes, you're correct about $I$, so in your example, you would just have to check that $f(a_2)^3 = 1$ and $f(a_1)f(a_2) + f(a_2)f(a_1) = 0$. As for the universal property, it's essentially exactly what I've said it is. This is actually a property held by free objects in many settings, and it's often useful to take it as a definition of 'free' object. It should not be hard to check the result yourself. Given a function $S \rightarrow B$, you should be able to see a clear way to extend it to a morphism $k[S] \rightarrow B$, and since $S$ generates $k[S]$, you can check this is the only one.

Comment: If I take $I=<a_i²|i\in I>$, why do we get the relation $a_ia_j+a_ja_i=0$?

Comment: Careful with overusing $I$ there. I'm not sure what you mean though. I don't see why we would get that relation.

Comment: Restart: $S=\{a_1,...a_n\}$ and $I=<a_i²|i\in I>$ the two sided ideal in $k[S]$. This quotient is the so called Grassmann algebra I think. Now we must get $a_ia_j+a_ja_i=0$, but I don't see why. If $(a_i+a_j)²\in I$, then I do see why.

Comment: I think you mean $I = \langle v^2 \mid v \in k[S] \rangle$. In that case you get the condition you wanted.

Comment: This I again don't understand because the Grassmann algebra is defined for a vector space $V$ to be the quotient of the tensor algebra of $V$ by the ideal generated by elements $v\otimes v$, where $v\in V$. Let us call the dimension of $V$ just $n$. Can you translate this Grassmann algebra definition into the free algebra setting? So let $S$ be as above, i.e. with elements $a_i$. Then what ideal would I quotient out of $k[S]$? The ideal generated by elements $v²$ where $v$ lives in $S$, the linear $k$-span of elements $a_i$ or $k[S]$?